# Onclick Function sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to Javascript and I've recently been trying a sidebar menu.

I am trying to make the menu come out from the left side and overlay the main content when the hamburger icon is clicked. I have managed to make the menu overlay the main content but when it comes to javascript animation, I have tried a couple of things and search on internet but found no solutions to my problem.

I am trying to make so that when the .hamburger button is clicked, the .nav-links div's width changes from 0px to 300px.

Here's my code and a couple of Javascript functions I have tried.

Here's my code

**HTML :**

```
<button class="hamburger">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
        </button>
            <div class="nav-links">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#">HEN</a>
                    <a href="#">BBG</a>
                    <a href="#">YSMB</a>
                    <div class="CloseBTN">&times;</div> 
                </ul>
            </div>`
```

**CSS**

`

```
.line {
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  margin: 5px;
}

.hamburger {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
  background: inherit;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
}

.nav-links {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: solid white 1px;
}
.nav-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  padding: 50px 8px 50px 64px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-links a:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

.CloseBTN {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('hamburger') = function openMenu(){
    document.getElementById('nav-links').menu.style.width="300px";
        }

 function openMenu(){
            if(document.getElementById('nav-links').click === true)
            document.getElementById('nav-links').menu.style.width="300px";  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('hamburger')[0].addEventListener("click", evt => {
  document.getElementsByClassName('nav-links')[0].style.width = "300px"
})
document.getElementsByClassName('CloseBTN')[0].addEventListener("click", evt => {
  document.getElementsByClassName('nav-links')[0].style.width = "0"
})
```

```css
.line {
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}

.hamburger {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
  background: inherit;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
}

.nav-links {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: solid white 1px;
}

.nav-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  padding: 50px 8px 50px 64px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-links a:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

.CloseBTN {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="hamburger">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
        </button>
<div class="nav-links">
  <ul>
    <a href="#">HEN</a>
    <a href="#">BBG</a>
    <a href="#">YSMB</a>
    <div class="CloseBTN">&times;</div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Some of your javascript was messed up so I fixed that, and I added some css to make everything (such as the actual menu lines itself) visible.

Comment: It works perfectly ! Thank you very much !